# Отсортировать список документов по количеству символов в Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, сортировка

Только начал учить Python. Надо отсортировать 1000 документов в формате html по количеству символов (до 250). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделть?

Comment: А документы где - уже в списке или в виде файлов лежат?

Comment: сортировка по кол-ву символов - some_list.sort(key = len)

Comment: Документы лежат в виде файлов

Comment: циклично открываете файлы, считаете кол-во символов, сохраняете результат, сортируете и выводите - каждый из шагов сам по себе прост.. "кто ищет, тот всегда найдет"